# F# - Convert CsvProvider Type To Existing Type

Tags: csv, f#, type-providers

I have an existing defined type, **XRecord**, and would like to convert the inferred CsvProvider type, **CsvRecord**, to XRecord or, alternatively, use XRecord as the schema for importing from csv. Note that CsvRecord will have the same or fewer columns as XRecord but will always include **ID** and **Class**.

Also, what happens if there are fewer attributes in the inferred type than in the existing type?

```
module SOQN =

    open System
    open System.IO
    open FSharp.Data

    type XRecord = 
        {
            ID          : string
            Class       : bool
            Alpha       : string
            Bravo       : string
            Charlie     : string
            Delta       : string
        }

    let [<Literal>] csvInput  = @"F:\data\Test.csv"
    type CsvRecord = CsvProvider<csvInput, ",">

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        let records = CsvRecord.Load(csvInput )
        printfn "\nFini!\n"
        0
```

Comment: If your *existing* type matches (a subset of) the CSV, I’d recommend using a JSON deserialization library (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json) instead of mapping the provided type. If the CSV has less information, the corresponding fields in XRecord will have their default values. Depending on the deserializer, `[CLIMutable]` attribute might be helpful. If you need some custom logic for initializing fields in XRecord not defined in the JSON, map manually.

Comment: For getting an answer with less `if`s, sharing a sample of your JSON would be helpful.